# Fluid Pressure: The Collision Model - Approximation or Truth?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics

> Microscopically, the pressure exerted by a fluid on a surface in contact with it is caused by collisions of molecules of fluid with the surface. As a result of a collision, the component of a molecule's momentum perpendicular to the surface is reversed. The surface must exert an impulsive force on the molecule, and by Newton's Third Law the molecule exerts an equal force perpendicular to the surface. The net result of reaction force exerted by many molecules on the surface gives rise to the pressure on the surface.

The above is an extract from Physics by Resnick, Halliday & Krane.

I've a few questions, conceptual in nature, which stemmed from the above paragraph -

1. All that is mentioned is that the component of molecule's momentum perpendicular to surface is reversed; nothing is mentioned about its magnitude. If, they wish to tell us that the collision is elastic (as in the case of kinetic theory of gases), why is this a valid assumption? Maybe, the right question to ask is, to what extent is it a valid assumption?
2. According to the aforementioned extract, pressure arises due to collisions between molecules and the surface. It is also a well known fact that pressure in a static fluid increases with depth. How can we explain that using this collision model? I'm confused because, **the nature of collisions should be a property of the fluid, and should not vary with depth.**
3. Is this model - the one that talks about pressure arising due to collisions, sufficient to explain pressure related phenomena in all possible situations; or is it a mere approximation?

Comment: No, the collisions of molecules cannot be considered to be elastic. The collisions can cause the molecules to vibrate. Thus, initial kinetic energy is not necessarily equal to the final kinetic energy. Some energy can be stored as potential energy.

Comment: For a system in thermal and mechanical equilibrium, the non-elastic nature of the collisions (both with the walls and between molecules) is of no significance because the energy gains and losses come out in the wash (get it? get it?). But in general you need to be looking at the time evolution of the system to understand the importance of any inelasticity that may be present (it is quite absent in the most spherical and bovine models).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The quoted paragraph from the textbook talks about *fluids* which usually includes gases, liquids, and plasmas.  However, it would not be right to say that for liquids (e.g., consider water for concreteness) the pressure is the kinetic pressure $P_k=nkT$. First of all, we know that we can put water under a piston and increase the pressure isothermically at nearly constant density. If the pressure is due to particle collisions then why does it increase without any increase of temperature and density? Furthermore, using the numbers for water at normal conditions, $n=33e27 m^{-3}$, T=300 K, we'd get the kinetic pressure $P_k$ at about 10 million atmospheres, but we don’t see it!

We don't see this huge pressure because it is largely compensated by intermolecular attraction forces. So the total pressure in a liquid is $P = P_k + P_f$, where $P_f$ (negative at normal conditions) is the component of the pressure due to intermolecular forces, strongly dependent on the density. If water is compressed (at a constant temperature) the resulting pressure increase is due to the change of $P_f$.

So, for water compressed under a piston at a constant temperature, the total observed pressure increases; the thermal pressure caused by water molecules bouncing off the surface does not change in this process but the intermolecular forces respond to the compression changing the total pressure.

Given that the thermal pressure in a liquid is almost entirely compensated by the intermolecular forces, one can model a liquid as a large number of slippery almost incompressible balls lumped together, essentially excluding thermal motion from the picture. This model would have the properties of a real fluid (weakly compressible, isotropic pressure, Pascal law, Archimedes law). If we put such a "liquid" in a vertical column then we'd observe that those balls deeper down from the surface are compressed more (because there is a larger weight above them), and a body embedded in this “liquid” deeper would experience a larger external pressure.

Comment: How do you explain using this model that the pressure in a liquid is isotropic?

Comment: [This](https://michaelberryphysics.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/berry018.pdf) (p. 81) paper by Michael Berry says that the pressure is a sum of (1)the pressure due to collisions(due to thermal agitations) (2) the intermolecular attractive forces. Is he wrong? I'm not able to understand.

Comment: @Apoorv Potnis Well, that paper by Michael Berry discusses surface tension. That's why he talks there about attractive forces. I was talking about repulsive forces that are responsible for liquids' small compressibility.  Thermal motion is a component of pressure in a liquid but I don't think it is anything significant for water at room temperature, its pressure can be increased by orders of magnitude by compression, without any significant increase of temperature or density.

Comment: But isn't the equation that he states for total pressure always valid?

Comment: @Apoorv Potnis Well, this is a strongly non-ideal gas situation. The actual equation of state is something complex. But the total pressure can be always formally split into a sum of ideal-like thermal components and the rest, like that paper by Michael Berry paper does.

Comment: Then how to explain using his equation that pressure increases along with an increase in depth? Which component of the pressure contributes? Unless the pressure is very great, then the static component of pressure cannot be positive. This means that the kinetic pressure should increase. But density remains more or less the same, doesn't it?

Comment: @Apoorv Potnis I think the resolution is like this: The thermal pressure p=nkT in a liquid is nearly compensated by the attractive forces. That’s why we don’t see the thermal pressure there (which would be huge, the density is a thousand times more than that of for a gas under normal conditions). But once the liquid is compressed, the attractive forces are reduced (static forces strongly depend on the distance) so the net pressure increases. In fact, this explanation would partially reconcile with the views in the Resnick et al. textbook. What do you think?

Comment: I too was thinking on the same lines but I'm facing a problem. If attractive forces are reduced due to compression, does this mean that average intermolecular distance decreases? Then this should be reflected in an increase in density, shouldn't it?

Comment: I think it would be better if one can prove that the density increases only slightly in such a way that intermolecular forces, which have sharp dependence on density, change a lot but the kinetic pressure does not change appreciably.

Comment: One would need to show that the static pressure increases linearly with depth. I don't know how to derive static pressure as a function of density. (I'm still in high-school)

Comment: The static pressure responds to the weight of liquid (or externally imposed pressure) to maintain a static equilibrium. Since the weight goes linearly with depth so does the static pressure. Let's move this to chat to discuss further.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74365/discussion-between-apoorv-potnis-and-maxim-umansky).

Answer (score 6):

1. The model is a very good approximation as long as the mass of the molecules colliding with the surface have negligible individual mass and cross section with respect to the surface they are hitting. The number density of molecules also matters in some cases because more molecules means more internL forces, which might have an impact on their collision rates and momentum change.
2. Fluid pressure increases with depth because there are more particles above than below. Consider any surface in the fluid parallel to the base. There is a certain distribution of particles above and below it. As you move the surface down, the number of particles above it increase whereas there is a decrease in the number below it. This causes more net pressure ro be exerted downwards and hence the variation with depth.
3. As you have already mentioned in the first part, and as I have answered, it is an approximation. The Real Gas equation is a better model (for gases) and there are several others. But for most situations involving low density, low pressure and moderate temperatures, such approximations are quite valid.

Cheers!

Comment: I disagree with the fact that number of particles increase; don't we assume the density to be fairly constant in our usual derivations?

Comment: @schrodinger_16 The number of particles increases in the sense that since the volume above the surface increases, the number of particles – which is the number density times the volume – increases ( since the number density is fairly constant as you point out).

Comment: Also, I understand the fact that fluid pressure increases with depth due to more particles above than below; however, I was looking for a purely collision based answer and my doubt still remains - if the collisions are characteristic to the fluid, there should be no variation.

Comment: The increase in the number of particles would directly imply more collisions and hence the increased pressure. And collision is not characteristic to a fluid (At least in our approximations it is not).

Comment: Wait, which collision are you talking about? We're only concerned with molecules colliding with the surface of the boundary, right? In fact, the collisions at only that particular depth should be able to determine the pressure at that depth - then how does the greater number of molecules above that level influence pressure in any way? Hope you get what I'm asking.

Comment: When collisions occur in a fluid, it is in general assumed that on an average all particles (that satisfy the Boltzmann energy law) collide with the surface. Thus, the number of particles is directly related to pressure. (Take for an example the ideal gas equation PV=NkT. N is the number of molecules. I hope the dependence is visible?)

Comment: For a liquid like water under a piston, the pressure can be increased isothermally without any significant change of density. This suggests that collisions are not responsible for it. The pressure is due to Van der Waals forces that prevent molecules from coming close to each other.

Comment: @MaximUmansky How does that address the fact that pressure increases with depth?

Comment: @schrodinger_16 Imagine a large number of very slippery rubber balls put in a vertical column. Those balls deeper down from the surface will be compressed more (because there is larger weight above them), and a body embedded in this “liquid” deeper would experience larger external pressure. This is completely analogous to a real liquid made from spherically symmetric molecules. In both cases the pressure has nothing to do with thermal motion.

Comment: Hmm. Makes sense. Is Resnick Halliday Krane incorrect, then? Also, I think you should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Some models look at the energy required to change a solid to a liquid and the energy required to change a liquid to a gas.   And conclude that liquids are similar to solids.  Molecules are connected by molecular bonds.   The bond strength in solids is greater than the bond strength for liquids.  EG...   water at 32 F    solid to gas hig = 1218.5 btu/lbm    and liquid to gas hfg =  1075.15 btu/lbm.    And thus solid to liquid hif  143.35 btu/lbm.
i.e.strong bond in liquids and stronger bond in solids

**Therefore hydrostatic pressure is due to weight of mass not due to individual molecular collisions of free gas molecules.**